# How to underline warnings in CLion default theme?

Tags: intellij-idea, clion

I have noticed that in CLion, with the Darcula theme, warnings are underlined like this:

[image]

But in the default IntelliJ theme, they are not:

[image]

How can I activate this behaviour, underlining all warnings, not just errors, in the default IntelliJ theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search `warings` in `Preferences` , click the result in `Color Scheme -> general`.

[image]

You can check `Effects` choose any effect you like with color (The default is white so not working ), for example `Underwaved`.

[image]

---

In fact the Darcular default is `Underwaved` with color `AEAE80`

[image]